# Gulp won't run correctly

Tags: bootstrap-4, gulp

I am doing the tutorial found here to learn Bootstrap 4: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnCmSXCZEpU&t=484s

When came time to run the gulp command, the gulp command was not found. After looking around I found the solution was to add the Gulp CLI packages which I did.

Now the Gulp command runs but instead of getting the red screen the tutorial depicts I get the following error:

```
assert.js:373
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\alexm\bs4\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\alexm\bs4\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alexm\bs4\gulpfile.js:21:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:731:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:644:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:771:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at execute (C:\Users\alexm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:36:18) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that tutorial is using gulp v3 and you have gulp v4+ installed.  You would have to show the gulpfile.js for us to help.

Comment: yeah, I had to downgrade my gulp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer to Question

Downgrade to Gulp 3

Comment: I would think that the more sustainable approach would be to fix the underlying problem, and upgrade your script to be compatible with the new Gulp 4 format.

Comment: Agreed, but my issue was with following this particular tutorial, so my answer was in the mindset of how do you follow it successfully. But agreed, if you are creating a new project, use the latest version.